# Xcode13 - Legacy Build System deprecated, unable to install to device with New Build System

Tags: ios, xcode

Legacy Build System has been deprecated since Xcode10+ but can still choose to use it. In the newest xcode Xcode13 you would encounter an error if attempt to use it - [release note reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13-release-notes)

We were able to get our App build to device using the New Build System but it only works on the initial build. The subsequent builds will encounter a `Unable To Install` error. We find that reopen Xcode, close out simulators, clearing derivedData, Clean Build folder would make the build work again but only once then the "Unable To Install" error would appear again.

Anyone have suggestions or workaround for this specific error on this build of Xcode?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There should be an option in Xcode 13 to keep using the legacy build system. File-> Workspace Settings -> Check "Don't show a diagnostic issue about build system deprecation" and click done.

Comment: In the newest xcode Xcode13 you would encounter an error if attempt to use it - release note reference